# How can I perform fastload for a file which has only one column and 'n' rows?

Tags: utilities, teradata

I have done fastload for table which has more than one column (I did this with vartext format with `,` as delimiter).

Now I want to load a file which has only one column (and 5 rows to say). But I'm unable to do that and encountering the below error:

```
I/O Error on File Read: 16, Text: Unexpected data format
```

My fastload script is as below:

```
SESSIONS 5;

.LOGON dbc/dbc.dbc;
BEGIN LOADING MYTABLE
ERRORFILES
TABLE_FLET,
TABLE_FLUV ;

DEFINE
COL1_MYTABLE (CHAR(2))
FILE = C:\Fload\INPT.TXT;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE
(
COL1_MYTABLE
)
VALUES
(
:COL1_MYTABLE
);

END LOADING;
```

MyTable structure is as below:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE database.MYTABLE ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
     (
      COL1_MYTABLE CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
      )
      PRIMARY INDEX ( COL1_MYTABLE );
```

the contents of the input file is as below:

```
AA
BB
CC
DD  
EE
```

How can I do this fastload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.. with the below script  :

```
.LOGON DBC/DBC,DBC;

CREATE MULTISET TABLE DATABASE.MYTABLE ,NO FALLBACK ,  
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,  
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,  
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT  
     (  
      COL1_MYTABLE CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)  
PRIMARY INDEX ( COL1_MYTABLE );  


BEGIN LOADING MYTABLE  
ERRORFILES  
        TABLE_FLET,  
        TABLE_FLUV  
;  

<b>SET RECORD TEXT;  </b>  
DEFINE  
COL1_MYTABLE (CHAR(2))  
FILE = C:\Fload\INPT.TXT;  

SHOW;  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE  
(  
COL1_MYTABLE  
)  
VALUES  
(  
:COL1_MYTABLE  
);  

END LOADING;
```